# How to add additional filter to crosstab query in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I have a crosstab query which looks like:

[image: Masterfile.png]

It returns:

**Response |**
       **Agent1 |**
       **Agent2 |**
       **Agentt3**
     



    
     
      Response1 |
           1      |
                   |
          4
     



    
         
      Response2 |
                    |
                    |
           2
      



    
      
       Response3 |
            5      |
                    |
           6
      



    
      
          **Total**        
            **6      |**
            **0      |**
         **12**

I have field 'Date' in my table, but when I add it in the crosstab query as 'Row Heading' (right next to Response column) and try to use it on order to filter the data, I got an error message: **'Cannot use the crosstab of a non-fixed column as a subquery'**.

I was wondering if there is a way to add a filter option by date in the crosstab or how I can handle with that error above?

Also, one more thing: is there a way to hide any column in the query which doesn't have data in it's respective rows (For example: **Agent2** column in the example above)?

Comment: Is [Masterfile] a local Access table and [Date] a normal `Date/Time` field in that table? (I just tried to recreate your query and mine ran without errors.)

Comment: [Masterfile] is my main table which is the source of the described query and yes, [Date] is a normal Date/Time field in that table.

Comment: I have uploaded my test file to Wikisend. If you feel so inclined you can download it [here](http://wikisend.com/download/612712/xtabTest.zip) and see if there is any significant difference that could explain why my query works and yours doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Gord, it looks like it works this way, but I forgot to mention that I also set a 'Criteria' in the query [Response] column. For example: "Response1" Or "Response2". Maybe this is the reason for the error I get. Also, do you know how to not show the columns in the query which doesnt have any values (like 'Agent2' in the example)?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really comment on that because Crosstab queries normally *don't* display columns with no results. Usually the issue is the opposite: people want to show columns even if they don't contain values (accomplished via an `IN(...)` clause). It seems that your query is somewhat different than what your question describes. If you want to post a sample database file to Wikisend I'd be willing to take a look at it.